# My phone is stuck on booting loop

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy Young. Yesterday it suddenly switched off and is turning on but stuck on a lopp. I can not boot into recovery mode it has stuck in some kind of loop. Please help me I have tried flashing the stock ROM but it does not help. Even when I plugin the charger it shows same loop. This is a video of the loop I have recorded:

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t38NYXvawmxSiIK9gqRTLINoIvG158Vi6w/view?usp=drivesdk)

My phone is **samsung galaxy young GT-S6312**. It is running on android 4.1.2 Jellybean.
Please somebody tell me what is the problem and what probably is the solution.

Comment: From your description I get fact that the device can be turned on but it does not boot up. "not turning on" usually means it is completely dead (no reaction pressing the power button).

Comment: Maybe you flashed the wrong stock rom. It happens. Try again.

Comment: https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-young/GT-S6312/ refer to this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe yor stockROM has failed in retrieving your phone because of some errors in it. It would be better if you download it again from the internet or just find the 4 files for your device and the pit file then flash them.

The 4 files are not available in all countries so if you find it is not in your country just flash it and then flash the single md5 that too will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your bootloader or recovery has been messed up. Were you trying to flash anything while this happened?
Best way to fix this is to get the phone in "Download Mode," then flash a new bootloader or recovery. To enter into download mode, press and hold the volume down, home and power buttons together until you enter the download mode. From there, you can flash a new recovery image over. Make sure the recovery image is specific to your phone model.

Comment: I already mentioned that flashing stock ROM using does not solve my problem then why this answer?

Comment: @MEDLEY There are 3 parts to your phone: the bootloader, the recovery and the Android system (often called a ROM). If your bootloader or recovery are messed up, your phone will not boot. Flashing another ROM will not fix your bootloader or your recovery, those are separate things.

Comment: I did not flash other ROM. I flashed the stock ROM for my device using odin3. It contains all parts of the OS for my phone.